# what is function can print big number correctly php?

Tags: php, numbers

i have this number

```
echo $sum;
output: 4.9165167059184E+24.343377414
```

I want it to be printed correctly

Comment: [a] how is the number generated? [b] what do *you* think **printed correctly** means?

Comment: I suggest you run `var_dump($sum)` to check the variable data type. In any case, PHP [exponential notation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) does not allow fractional exponents so this must surely be a text. And it doesn't, for a good reason: using fractional exponents defeats the purpose of using powers of 10.

Answer (score -3):

Your output is in scientific notation,if you want to print exact number you just typecast the value explicitly

For example

```
(String) $result=$sum;
echo $result;
```